# Why material folder is not showing up under ng_modules/@angular?

Tags: angular-material, angular6

I am setting up angular material in angular6. I have installed material and imported BrowserAnimationModule in AppModule. But the material folder under ng_module/@angular is still not visible.

I have used the command to install angular-material: npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations.
After this importing modules and components required in AppModule.

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
...
...

I am not able to use angular-material. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you imported material styles css? Eg:@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"; in your style.css file?

Comment: @sah1 Yes, I included the import statement in style.css.

Comment: @Abhinandan Did you followed every step needed to install [material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) in angular project

Comment: try uninstall and then install... `npm uninstall @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations` and then `npm install @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations`

Comment: @nitin9nair Yes, I followed each step to install material.

Comment: @Abhinandan can you give the versions from package.json file for the relevant dependencies?
Make sure you are installing the ones compatible with angular 6

Comment: Yes. I was related to the versions of @angular/material and @angular/cdk. I changed them to compatible ones and it worked. Thanks guys for the suggestions.